# Finding a probability with two independent variables

Tags: probability

Problem:

Suppose that $x$ and $y$ are two independent uniformly distributed
random variables on the interval $[0,10]$.  What is the probability
that $xy^2$ will be greater than $20$.

Answer:

Let $p$ be the probability that we seek. Let $q$ be the probability that
$xy^2$ will be less than $20$.
\begin{align*}
p + q &= 1 \\
q &=
 \dfrac{1}{100} \int_0^{10} \int_{0}^{\dfrac{20}{y^2}} x y^2 \,\,  dx \,\, dy \\
%
q &=
\dfrac{1}{100} \int_0^{10}
 \dfrac{ x^2 y^2 }{2} \Big|_{x = 0}^{x = \dfrac{20}{y^2}} \,\, dy \\
%
q &=
 \dfrac{1}{200} \int_0^{10} \dfrac{ 400 }{ y^2} \,\, dy \\
q &= 2 \int_0^{10} y^{-2} \,\, dy \\
q &= -2y^{-1}\Big|_{0}^{10} \\
q &= 2y^{-1}\Big|_{10}^{0} \\
q &= \infty - \dfrac{2}{10} \\
q &= \infty
\end{align*}
Hence my solution is wrong. Where did I go wrong?

By doing simulation in a Python Script, I found that 0.7372 is an estimate of the answer. If asked, I would be happy to post the script.

Here is an updated answer which I now believe is correct:

Let $p$ be the probability that we seek.
\begin{align*}
p &=
 \int_{\sqrt{2}} ^{10} \int_{\dfrac{20}{y^2}}^{10} \dfrac{dx}{100} \,\, dy \\
%
\dfrac{p}{100} &=
 \int_{\sqrt{2}} ^{10} \int_{\dfrac{20}{y^2}}^{10} \,\,  dx \,\, dy \\
%
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
\text{Let } I &=
 \int_{\sqrt{2}} ^{10} \int_{\dfrac{20}{y^2}}^{10} \,\, dx \,\, dy \\
p &= \dfrac{I}{100} \\
I &= \int_{\sqrt{2}} ^{10} 10 - 20y^{-2} \,\, dy \\
I &= 10y + 20y^{-1} \Big|_{ \sqrt{2}}^{10} \\
I &= 10(10) + \dfrac{20}{ 10 } -
 \left(   10( \sqrt{2}) + \dfrac{20}{ \sqrt{2} } \right) \\
I &= 100 + 2 - \left(   10( \sqrt{2}) + \dfrac{20 \sqrt{2}}{ 2 } \right) \\
I &= 102 \left(  20 \sqrt{2} \right) \\
I &\doteq 73.7157 \\
p &\doteq 0.737157
\end{align*}
I now believe my solution is correct. Could somebody confirm that for me?

Comment: The upper bound of $\frac{20}{y^2}$ gets to be larger than $10$ for $y < \sqrt{2},$ which means $x$ is taking values it shouldn't be. I think this can be corrected by changing the lower bound on $y$ to $\sqrt{2}$ and then adding $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{10}$ to the answer for the probability, since $x < 10$ and $y < \sqrt{2}$ guarantees $xy^2 < 20.$

Comment: Following up on the earlier comment, I realized I missed the more basic issue: we don't integrate the $xy^2$ itself for the probability, that wouldn't be part of the pdf. You were accidentally trying to find the expected value of $xy^2$ over the region where it's less than $20.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When $y\leq \surd 2$ then $xy^2<20$ holds for all $x$, when $y>\surd 2$ then $xy^2<20$ holds for only for $0\leq x< 20/y^2$.

So the domain we need to integrate over is  $\{0\leqslant y\leqslant \surd 2, 0\leqslant x\leqslant 10\}\cup\{\surd 2\lt y\leqslant 10, 0\leqslant x\lt 20/y^2\}$

$$\begin{align} q&= \mathsf P(XY^2\leqslant 20)\\ &= \iint_{0\leqslant x\leqslant 10~,~0\leqslant y\leqslant 10~,~xy^2\leqslant 20} \dfrac 1{100}\,\mathrm d (x,y)\\ &=\int_0^{10}\int_0^{\min\{10,20/y^2\}}\dfrac 1{100}\,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d y\\&=\int_0^{\surd 2}\int_0^{10}\dfrac 1{100}\,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d y+\int_{\surd 2}^{10}\int_0^{20/y^2}\dfrac 1{100}\,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d y
\end{align}$$

---

Alternatively, because the remaining support is $\{\surd 2\lt y\leqslant 10, 20/y^2\lt x\leqslant 10\}$, therefore:
$$\begin{align}p & =\mathsf P(XY^2 \gt 20) \\&= \iint_{0\leqslant x\leqslant 10~,~0\leqslant y\leqslant 10~,~xy^2\gt 20} \dfrac 1{100}\,\mathrm d (x,y) \\ &= \int_{\surd 2}^{10}\int_{{20/y^2}}^{10} \dfrac 1{100}\,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d y \end{align}$$